# Objective C Static Analysis with custom linter rules?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-analysis, lint

How do I set up static analysis for ios code that allows me to add custom rules?

Comment: Did you try to use [OCLint](http://maniacdev.com/2013/01/altertnative-objective-c-static-code-analyzer-with-complexity-checkingeasily-customizable-rules)? It has possibility to create custom rules. It is alternative to standard Clang analyzer.

Comment: That sounds great! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [OCLint](http://maniacdev.com/2013/01/altertnative-objective-c-static-code-analyzer-with-complexity-checkingeasily-customizable-rules). It has possibility to create custom rules. It is alternative to standard Clang analyzer.